# Pytest error: AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'fixture'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm trying to use `@pytest.fixture(scope="class")`, but am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'fixture'
```

Am I using the wrong Pytest version? My version is `7.2.1`

I tried `@pytest.fixture(scope="class")` and got an error

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import os

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    supported_browsers= ['chrome' , 'firefox']

    browser = os.environ.get('BROWSER')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    if not browser:
        raise Exception("The environment variable 'BROWSER' must be set")
    browser = browser.lower()
    if browser not in supported_browsers:
        raise Exception(f"Provided browser '{browser}' is not supported"
                        f"Supported browsers are: {supported_browsers}")
    if browser in ('chrome'):
        driver = webdriver
    elif browser in ('firefox'):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: This does not repoduce. I just did `pip install 'pytest==7.2.1'` and then `@pytest.fixture(scope='class') def make_foo(): yield 'foo'` in `test_foo.py`, added a simple `assert True` test. and `pytest` invocation succeded with 1 passing test. Please share more details about used pytest plugins, platform used, venv/virtualenv/..., etc. The code you added also does not fail.

Comment: Have you called a file `pytest.py`?